# How do I modify a string's value with an if statement in Android?

Tags: android, string, if-statement, textview

I'm attempting to change a string's value with an if statement in Android and I'm having great difficulty in getting it to work. Essentially, I want a TextView to display a message that changes depending on the conditions of an if statement. Here is my code:

```
public void header()
{
    TextView streamBanner;
    streamBanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streamBanner);

    String streamName = "";

    if (Global.kittensOrient == true)
    {
        "Kittens".equals(streamName);
    }
    else if (Global.puppiesOrient == true)
    {
        "Puppies".equals(streamName);
    }
    else if (Global.ducklingsOrient == true)
    {
        "Ducklings".equals(streamName);
    }

    streamBanner.setText("Now streaming on " + streamName);
}
```

What's happening is the TextView will show the "Now streaming on " that it's been programmed to show, but streamName is appearing as blank. I feel like this is a simple solution, but I'm just having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: where you are assigning value to `streamName`? because in if-else blocks you are just checking streamName is equals to some string or not using String.equals method which return result as true or false

Comment: `.equals()` is a method that tests equality, it doesn't assign values.  Review the tutorial on operators, and the documentation for the equals method (and any other method you use for the first time)

Comment: Why is the question getting downvotes? He explained his question well, even though it's a simple problem.

Comment: Manu, I have no idea why I'm being downvoted, but I got my answer down below the other day. thanks for having my back though!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void header()
{
    TextView streamBanner;
    streamBanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streamBanner);

    String streamName = "";

    if (Global.kittensOrient == true)
    {
        streamName = "Kittens";
    }
    else if (Global.puppiesOrient == true)
    {
         streamName = "Puppies";
    }
    else if (Global.ducklingsOrient == true)
    {
           streamName = "Ducklings";
    }

    streamBanner.setText("Now streaming on " + streamName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `streamName = "Kittens"?` Are you sure one of the values gets true?

Answer (score 0):

You check in your Code if streamName contains "Ducklings" etc. with "Ducklings".equals(streamName);
Why you don't use streamName = "Ducklings" ?

Answer (score -2):

Assign the `String` value to your `"streamName"` variable of your `TextView` and then check for the value as below:

Try out as below:

```
public void header()
{
   TextView streamBanner;
   streamBanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streamBanner);

String streamName = "";

if (Global.kittensOrient == true)
{
    streamName.equalsIgnoreCase("Kittens");
}
else if (Global.puppiesOrient == true)
{
    streamName.equalsIgnoreCase("Puppies");
}
else if (Global.ducklingsOrient == true)
{
    streamName.equalsIgnoreCase("Ducklings");
}

streamBanner.setText("Now streaming on " + streamName);
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but he wants to change the text of the editText depending on the if statement. Obviously he should use `=` instead of `equals`.

Comment: I just do not understand why people are downvoting though my answer is not wrong.

Comment: It is wrong...Your code just adds "Now streaming on" to the textBanner. Nothing else.

Comment: @GrIsHu Kya 6? kam 6.